# Docker + Keycloak + IIS Reverse Proxy: calls to External Idp "/authorize" endpoint Base Url being replaced by proxy domain name

Tags: docker, iis, keycloak, reverse-proxy, idp

I have a dockerized keycloak container, running inside a vpn with an IIS reverse proxy which seems to be overwriting the **login.microsoftonline.com/[tenantId]/.../authorize** endpoint url with the proxy domain name when trying to login to microsoft through a Keycloak OIDC identity provider.

My setup as follows:
Ubuntu Linux running docker+Keycloak:22.01 (Quarkus) running as production
Windows Server 2019 running IIS Reverse Proxy with valid SSL certificates
All under the same VPN

The reverse proxy: **www.example_kcproxy.com** points to **example_private_ip:port**
As recommended by the Keycloak docs, I have the reverse proxy setting Forwarded-For, Forwarded-Port, Forwarded-Host, Forwarded-Proto headers to respective values (web.config):

```
<serverVariables>
 <set name="HTTP_X_Forwarded_Proto" value="https" />
 <set name="HTTP_X_Forwarded_For" value="{HTTP_X_Forwarded_For},{REMOTE_ADDR}"/>
 <set name="HTTP_X_Forwarded_Host" value="{HTTP_HOST}" />
</serverVariables>
```

**My docker-compose config (Keycloak environment section):**

```
KEYCLOAK_PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING: 1
KEYCLOAK_FRONTEND_URL: https://www.example_kcproxy.com/
KC_HOSTNAME_ADMIN_URL: https://www.example_kcproxy.com/
KC_HOSTNAME_STRICT: 1
KC_PROXY: edge
KC_HOSTNAME: www.example_kcproxy.com
KC_HOSTNAME_STRICT_HTTPS: 1
```

I've tried different settings and combinations of settings. this is just my final config that is stable and production ready.

So everything works perfectly fine through the reverse proxy. I can admin my way through the Keycloak front end, configure Identity Providers, clients, realms e.t.c

I've successfully setup an OIDC Identity Provider that brokers for Microsoft Azure AD login.
I've tested this setup without a reverse proxy directly on the VPN and I can successfully login through Microsoft from the Keycloak admin.

Great, all good! however, when I introduce the reverse proxy, all keycloak admin related stuff works perfectly EXCEPT when I try login through the Microsoft IdP. The Microsoft Authorization Url ,e.g. **login.microsoftonline.com/[tenantId]/.../authorize** that Keycloak needs to use to redirect me to the Microsoft Login consent screen get's its base url replaced with **www.example_kc_proxy.com**. So then I get **www.example_kcproxy.com/[tenantId]/.../authorize**. Which is incorrect.... and this is my issue.

I'm almost certain the Keycloak is using the reverse proxy headers to construct this url which is interestig, because I have the correct url specified as the Authorization Url when setting up an Identtity Provider for the Keycloak realm. When I remove the X-Forwarded* headers, Keycloak still replaces the Microsoft login domain url but this time with **example_private_ip:port**, which is essentially the same issue, just the actual keycloak server IP.

I'm probably missing some config setting to ensure Keycloak does not overwrite the login.microsoftonline.com url for the authorize endpoint on microsoft.

So dunno, I'm stuck here lol. any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

ok,

looks like the issue, specific to IIS reverse proxy, was an Application Request Routing (ARR) configuration setting on the IIS server itself. the "ReverseRewriteHostInResponseHeaders" check box needed to be unchecked. Now, the original login.microsoftonline.com is not overwritten with the proxy site address.

refer: [Avoid rewriting URL's to external applications with reverse proxy on IIS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24908815/avoid-rewriting-urls-to-external-applications-with-reverse-proxy-on-iis)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).